# Snowflake DB join on Timestamp field auto conversion issue

Tags: join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, timestamp-with-timezone

I have two tables both of which have a timestamp field [TIMESTAMP_TZ] and when I perform a join based on this timestamp field the plan in snowflake DB shows an auto conversion on these timestamps into LTZ. Ex
(TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(CAG.LOAD_DATE_UTC) = TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(PIT.CSAT_AGREEMENT_LDTS))
Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

TIMESTAMP_TZ means your timestamp is linked to a time zone and TIMESTAMP_LTZ is your local timezone. Probably the timezones of your two timestamps are different and thus Snowflake converts them automatically to your local timezone to match them correctly.